# Notification upon Monitor enter/release Object

Tags: c#, .net

I feel like I might be re-inventing the wheel here. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

When an object is locked using `lock` or `Monitor.Enter`, I would like to receive a notification. Similarly, when the object is released I would like to have a notification.

I am thinking about writing a wrapper class that exposes an observable to send notifications, and a couple of methods to acquire/release the lock. But, like I mentioned, I feel like I might be redoing something that already exists. Any .NET techniques I could use to achieve this with out writing a new class?

EDIT:
To answer some questions:
Why? I need to know when a piece of code is busy before even trying to execute. Lets assume that we have two buttons on the UI, A and B. A executes methodA, and B executes methodB. They both use the same object to lock/sync. I would like to disable these buttons when I see someone is already executing a piece of code that is locked by the sync object instance _syncObject. I would like to give the user an indication that the function can't be executed at the moment.

Monitor.TryEnter , or trying to verify if the lock is available is not a solution, since it requires polling and is not a notification.

```
void methodA()
{
lock(_syncObject)
{
...
}
}

void methodB()
{
{
lock(_syncObject)
{
...
}
}
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to, even if you could.  Chances are you have a problem with your design if you want to do this.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This is not built-in for sure. Maybe we can answer better if we know the "why".

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't set a "busy" flag at the start of your lock block and use standard mechanisms (`INotifyPropertyChanged`, for example) to update your UI?

Comment: @DanPuzey Couple of things: There are more methods than just methodA and methodB that use the _syncObject. I will have to set/unset this busy flag in all these methods. Second, I might have simplified my example here, but lets assume that there is WCF transport layer in between the UI and server code, INotifyPropertyChanged will not work in this instance.

Comment: If you're using a WCF transport layer, how will you fire any event for your client to see?  Perhaps this "disabling" behaviour is client-side only, and not related to the lock at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you're trying to do.
If you want some notification that some thread is executing the protected code section,
you can create set of events, so as soon as the code section start, you can fire event that the code is being executed... Same at the end, just before the lock is released.

Comment: I was thinking something similar to begin with, now assume that this lock object instance is used in several places, now I will have to add this event in all those places.

Answer (score 0):

The only "notification" you'll get is either that the `Monitor` is locked or that it has become unlocked.  For example:

```
   bool lockTaken;
   Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref lockTaken);
   if(!lockTaken) Console.WriteLine("Already locked");
   else Console.WriteLine("Not already locked.");
```

Monitors and other synchronization objects are meant to control threads, not for notification.  If you want notification of things occurring, create events and raise them--that's what events are for.

Comment: I am aware of events. Thanks!